# Embedded Postgres cannot obtain process PID on Mac OS

Tags: macos, java-11, embedded-postgres

I'm using [embedded PostgreSQL](https://github.com/yandex-qatools/postgresql-embedded) with Java 11 for integration testing. On Windows it runs fine, but on Mac it first downloads Mac OS binaries (which is expected):

```
Extract /Users/fubar/.embedpostgresql/postgresql-11.1-1-osx-binaries.zip START
```

But then it fails with the following stacktrace:

```
java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: handle
at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredField(Class.java:2411)
at de.flapdoodle.embed.process.runtime.Processes.windowsProcessId(Processes.java:109)
at de.flapdoodle.embed.process.runtime.Processes.access$200(Processes.java:51)
at de.flapdoodle.embed.process.runtime.Processes$PidHelper$2.getPid(Processes.java:209)
```

When I look into `Processes` source code I see that internally it uses `PidHelper.LEGACY`, that fails the first attempt to obtain pid via `unixLikeProcessId()`.

Could anyone, please, give a hint why this is happenning or how to fix that?

Comment: I don't know anything about Embedded Progress. Have you checked their issue tracker to see if there is a newer version that fixes this issue? The Process::pid method is the simplest way to get the pid since JDK 9.

Answer (score 0):

Logs revealed the following:

```
Possibly failed to run initdb:
initdb: invalid locale name "en-US"
```

So the `initdb` failed, PostgeSQL instance didn't start and didn't create a `postmaster.pid` file, which all led to the error above.

The problem was in locale that was configured via `additionalInitDbParams=[--locale=en-US, -EUTF8]`.